# how to join multiple sorted files in Python alphabetically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

How can I read multiple CSV input files line by line, compare the characters in each line, write the line appearing first alphabetically to an output file, and then advance the pointer of the minimum value's file to continue the comparisons with all files until the end of all input files is reached. Here's some rough planning toward a solution.

```
buffer = []

for inFile in inFiles:

    f = open(inFile, "r")
    line = f.next()
    buffer.append([line, inFile])

#find minimum value in buffer alphabetically...
#write it to an output file...

#how do I advance one line in the file with the min value?
#and then continue the line-by-line comparisons in input files?
```

Comment: Are the individual files already in order?

Comment: Yes, the individual files contain words ordered alphabetically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

```
import heapq
import contextlib

files = [open(fn) for fn in inFiles]
with contextlib.nested(*files):
    with open('output', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(heapq.merge(*files))
```

In Python 3.x (3.3+):

```
import heapq
import contextlib

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fn)) for fn in inFiles]
    with open('output', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(heapq.merge(*files))
```

Comment: hehe... exactly what I was thinking :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know about heapq. The issue is that inFile #1 can have "apple" and "grape" for example, but inFile #2 can have "banana", and inFile #3 can have "blueberry". Therefore, the order in the output file should read "apple", "banana", "blueberry", "grape".

Comment: @stevetronix, The code does what you expected. See this: http://asciinema.org/a/12788

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks for the demo link. What is the most efficient way to remove duplicate entries found in these files during the merge?

Comment: Thanks, well presented! The only issue is that this seems to bring all input files in memory at once and can be memory-intensive. I would like to reduce memory consumption by reading one line per input file at a time and then writing to the output file line by line.

Comment: @stevetronix, No, it does not load entire file contents at once. It just reads needed lines only from each file.

Comment: @stevetronix, If you follow the link in the answer, you will see: Similar to sorted(itertools.chain(*iterables)) **but returns an iterable, does not pull the data into memory all at once**, and assumes that each of the input streams is already sorted (smallest to largest).